# How to determine the trace and determinant of a differential operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, mathematical-physics, trace, functional-determinants

How to determine the trace and determinant of the operator like $\Box$ or $\nabla^2$ etc. But first of all how to find the same for the simpler operator $\frac{d}{dx}$? I proceeded as follows. What basis functions should I choose- $\{e^{ikx}\}$ or $\{\delta(x-x^\prime)\}$? Since, the first basis is the diagonal basis the calculation of trace and determinant will bee easier. The $kk^\prime$-matrix element is given by $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ikx}\frac{d}{dx}e^{ik^\prime x}=2\pi ik\delta(k-k^\prime).$$ Now the task is to determine the trace and the determinant. Since, in discrete case $$\sum\limits_{i,j} A_{ij}\delta_{ij}=\sum\limits_{i} A_{ii}$$ gives the trace of a matrix A. Then, can we find the trace as $$\int dk\int dk^\prime 2\pi ik\delta(k-k^\prime).$$ But the result is infinite! Is this approach correct?

**Edit** : If not please indicate the correct method and expected result.

Comment: Your approach is pretty good (pick the diagonal basis) and the divergence is correct but may not be as bad as it looks (at least if the context for this question is doing qft). You need to renormalize, meaning you can absorb the  divergence into some of the parameters of the theory. The canonical example of a calculation like this that I suggest looking up is the Coleman-Weinberg potential (it amounts to computing tr(log(box+V'') where V is a potential).

Answer (score 6):

In infinite dimensions, you can define the trace only for a special class of **compact operators**: the so-called trace-class operators. Given an Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, the space of trace class operators $\mathscr{I}_1(\mathscr{H})$ is a two-sided ideal of the bounded operators $\mathscr{L}(\mathscr{H})$.

The two operations $\mathrm{Tr}$ and $\mathrm{Det}(1+\cdot)$ defined as follows:
$$\mathrm{Tr}: A\mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(A)\; ,\; \mathrm{Det}(1+\cdot): A\mapsto \mathrm{Det}(1+A)\; ,$$
have the following properties:

- the first is a linear bounded functional on $\mathscr{I}_1(\mathscr{H})$;
- the second is a continuous function on $\mathscr{I}_1(\mathscr{H})$.

The operators you cite (all of them), are *unbounded*. So you cannot expect in any way that their trace (or determinant) should be finite, for it is like expecting that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n$ is finite.

Comment: Thai is not the idea used by physicists. All considered operators are not compact (sometime their resolvent is). The most popular procedures deal with some heat-kernel or $\zeta$-function regularization procedure. As a matter of fact if the resolvent is trace class they analytically continue the trace of an inverse power of the resolvent, as it happens in the definition of the $\zeta$ function...

Comment: @ValterMoretti: Renormalization of a determinant $\det M$ of an unbounded operator $M$ essentially consists of writing the operator $A$ as a product $M=M_0(1+A)$ where $A$ is trace class and $M_0$ is known. Then $\det M=\det M_0+\det (1+A)$ in any regularization. The (in the limit infinite) value $\det M_0$ must cancel rigorously in all observable quantities computed from this, in order that the regularization procedure is mathematically consistent. This reconciles your view with yuggib's (correct) answer.

Comment: @ValterMoretti would you have a reasonably recent and accessible source on this.  Target audience is an upper level physics student with pretty good math background.

Comment: Sorry I have not, I stopped many years ago (15 more or less when I was at the first stages of my career) dealing with these topics. I wrote a book (analytic aspects of quantum fields) published by World Scientific with other authors, but I suspect nowadays there are much  better sources.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier Can you recommend something modern and readable to a senior physics student with good background in math but not in functional analysis?   Ideally it would be approached from a physics perspective rather than a theorem perspective.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Think (as Heisenberg did) of operators as infinite matrices. The trace is defined only if the infinite sum of diagonal elements converges absolutely. Given an operator, you can represent it as infinite matrix by means of its matrix elements in any orthonormal basis. Maybe Volume 3 of Thirring's Mathematical Physics is suitable for you to introduce you to functional analysis in quantum physics, though it does not explicitly deal with the above problem.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier I will get the student to look up Thirring.  The problem we have is that our operators are not trace-class but the physical states are concentrated in one part of the Hilbert space (an irrep of SU(1,1)) so the hardcore math results won’t help and we probably need to use some physics argument to find (or not) a solution.  Physics suggests there ought to be a solution but it might have to be through an expansion on coherent states or something similar (rather than the weight basis) to capture this concentration feature.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: I added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 5):

Renormalization of a determinant $\det M$ of an unbounded operator $M$ 
is invariably of the following type:

It essentially consists of writing the operator $A$ as a product $M=M_0(1+A)$ where $A$ is trace class and $M_0$ is known. Then $\det M=\det M_0\det(1+A)$ in any regularization (i.e., representation by limits of bounded operators). The (in the limit infinite) value $\det M_0$ must cancel rigorously in all observable quantities computed from this, in order that the regularization procedure is mathematically consistent.

Typically, this infinite factor is the determinant of an exactly solvable system of which the determinant of interest can be considered as a (relatively compact) perturbation.

The book ''[Trace ideals and their applications](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a455/890a0fbec7e674d2d2a63355077cf5278ba3.pdf)'' by B. Simon 
discusses the regularization procedure in some detail in Chapter 9. 
(But for field theories in more than 2 dimensions, more stringent renormalization is needed than discussed there, to make $A$ trace class.)